# Passing data from two different intent in one activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

how can i pass different value from different intent inside another activity. i.e

Activity A:

ButtonA .onclick{

```
    intent.putExtra("name", screenname);

    intent.putExtra("email", description);

    intent.putExtra("pic", twitterImage);

    startActivity(intent);
```

}

ButtonB. onClick{

```
    intent.putExtra("anothervalue", json_object.toString())
```

}

Activity B:

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();

  String getValue = intent.getStringExtra("value from any of the button clicked")
```

Comment: The keys and values you use in the example are misleading. The key and value should be different and the same keys used in getStringExtra as were used in putExtra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While David Rauca answer is essentially correct, you will likely face `NullPointerException`.

`getIntent().getStringExtra("firstvalue")` will cause NPE if there is no value with name 'firstvalue'.

You should check whether or not value exist like this.

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("firstvalue")) {
    String firstvalue = getIntent().getStringExtra("firstvalue");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it and worked  but am still having one issue, i only tested for one item, actually the button A is sending more than on value,  i don't want to check if all is null, cus the value can be changed later, intent.putExtra("name", screenname);
        intent.putExtra("email", description);
        intent.putExtra("pic", twitterImage);
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: How about sending the whole object ?
Or check for differential value ?
e.g: A is sending name,email, pic and B is sending dob,password. You can check whether or not intent has `name` or `dob`. 
That way you can only need to check `name` and `dob`. And extract the rest accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

@Mandeep answer is correct. But if you have more values coming from activity then here is the solution. Thanks to Mandeep

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String getValue1,getValue2,getValue3;

if(i.hasExtra("AFirstValue") && i.hasExtra("ASecondValue") && i.hasExtra("AThirdValue")){ 

getValue1 = i.getStringExtra("AFirstvalue");
getValue2 = i.getStringExtra("ASecondValue");
getValue3 = i.getStringExtra("AThirdValue");

}

if(i.hasExtra("anotherFirstvalue") && i.hasExtra("anotherSecondvalue") && i.hasExtra("anotherThirdvalue")){

getValue1 = i.getStringExtra("anotherFirstvalue");
getValue2 = i.getStringExtra("anotherSecondvalue");
getValue3 = i.getStringExtra("anotherThirdvalue");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String getValue = intent.getStringExtra("firstvalue")  // in order to get the first value that was set when user clicked on buttonA
```

or

```
String getValue = intent.getStringExtra("anothervalue")  // in order to get the the value that was set when user clicked on buttonB
```

Answer (score 0):

`Activity B` code should be like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String firstvalue = intent.getStringExtra("firstvalue");
String anothervalue = intent.getStringExtra("anothervalue");

if(firstvalue != null)
    // called from Button A click
else if(secondvalue != null)
    // called from Button B click
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String getValue = null;

if(intent.hasExtra("firstvalue")){ 

getValue = intent.getStringExtra("firstvalue");

}

if(intent.hasExtra("anothervalue")){

 getValue = intent.getStringExtra("anothervalue");

}
```